# Jhipster input email NotBlank error

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, jhipster

I generated a Jhipster app, and I am trying to work on the user management part.

I removed the login field since I want my users to log from their email. 
I can log in, or create a new account from the home page.
But in the user management page I've got this error:

```
{
  "type" : "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/constraint-violation",
  "title" : "Method argument not valid",
  "status" : 400,
  "path" : "/api/users/resource",
  "message" : "error.validation",
  "fieldErrors" : [ {
    "objectName" : "userDTO",
    "field" : "email",
    "message" : "NotBlank"
  } ]
}
```

Here is my code:

> user-management-update.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="userManagement.email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" #emailInput="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.email" minlength="5" required maxlength="254" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" email>
        <div *ngIf="emailInput.dirty && emailInput.invalid">
            <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="emailInput.errors.required" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.required">
            This field is required.
            </small>
            <small class="form-text text-danger"
                    *ngIf="emailInput.errors.maxlength" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.maxlength"
                    translateValues="{max: 100}">
            This field cannot be longer than 100 characters.
            </small>
            <small class="form-text text-danger"
                    *ngIf="emailInput.errors.minlength" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.minlength"
                    translateValues="{min: 5}">
            This field is required to be at least 5 characters.
            </small>
            <small class="form-text text-danger"
                    *ngIf="emailInput.errors.email" jhiTranslate="global.messages.validate.email.invalid">
            Your email is invalid.
            </small>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- other inputs with no error -->
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="previousState()">
        <fa-icon [icon]="'ban'"></fa-icon>&nbsp;<span
                jhiTranslate="entity.action.cancel">Cancel</span>
    </button>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="editForm.form.invalid || isSaving" class="btn btn-primary">
        <fa-icon [icon]="'save'"></fa-icon>&nbsp;<span jhiTranslate="entity.action.save">Save</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I didn't change the TS part. I don't really understand the problem with the email, validation is fine when I type it (for example I use: "example@example.com") there is no "red", and I can click the button.

Here's the TS part, just in case:

> user-management-update.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-user-mgmt-update',
    templateUrl: './user-management-update.component.html'
})
export class UserMgmtUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
    user: User;
    promoters: Promoter[];
    promoter: Promoter;
    selectedPromoterId: number;
    languages: any[];
    authorities: any[];
    isSaving: boolean;

    constructor(
        private languageHelper: JhiLanguageHelper,
        private userService: UserService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private promoterService: PromoterService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.route.data.subscribe(({ user }) => {
            this.user = user.body ? user.body : user;
        });
        this.authorities = [];
        this.userService.authorities().subscribe(authorities => {
            this.authorities = authorities;
        });
        this.languageHelper.getAll().then(languages => {
            this.languages = languages;
        });
        this.promoterService.list().subscribe(response => (this.promoters = response.body), () => {}, () => {});
    }

    previousState() {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/user-management']);
    }

    save() {
        this.isSaving = true;
        if (this.user.id !== null) {
            this.userService
                .updateWithPromoter(this.user, this.selectedPromoterId)
                .subscribe(response => this.onSaveSuccess(response), () => this.onSaveError());
        } else {
            this.userService
                .createWithPromoter(this.user, this.selectedPromoterId)
                .subscribe(response => this.onSaveSuccess(response), () => this.onSaveError());
        }
    }

    onChange(value: any) {
        this.selectedPromoterId = value;
    }

    private onSaveSuccess(result) {
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.previousState();
    }

    private onSaveError() {
        this.isSaving = false;
    }
}
```

> user.service.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
    private resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/users';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    create(user: IUser): Observable<HttpResponse<IUser>> {
        return this.http.post<IUser>(this.resourceUrl, user, { observe: 'response' });
    }

    createWithPromoter(user: IUser, promoterId: number): Observable<HttpResponse<{ IUser, number }>> {
        return this.http.post<{ IUser, number }>(this.resourceUrl + '/resource', { user, promoterId }, { observe: 'response' });
    }

    update(user: IUser): Observable<HttpResponse<IUser>> {
        return this.http.put<IUser>(this.resourceUrl, user, { observe: 'response' });
    }

    updateWithPromoter(user: IUser, promoterId: number): Observable<HttpResponse<{ IUser, number }>> {
        return this.http.put<{ IUser, number }>(this.resourceUrl + '/resource', { user, promoterId }, { observe: 'response' });
    }

    find(login: string): Observable<HttpResponse<IUser>> {
        return this.http.get<IUser>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${login}`, { observe: 'response' });
    }

    query(req?: any): Observable<HttpResponse<IUser[]>> {
        const options = createRequestOption(req);
        return this.http.get<IUser[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' });
    }

    delete(login: string): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
        return this.http.delete(`${this.resourceUrl}/${login}`, { observe: 'response' });
    }

    authorities(): Observable<string[]> {
        return this.http.get<string[]>(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/users/authorities');
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add a custom API endpoint?  Where does `/api/users/resource` come from?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to add that part, I'll edit the post right now.

Comment: As far I as went in debug, it doesn't go to the java part (backend) of the project. It's stopped before sending the API call, if I'm not wrong.